# How does pointwise Hölder continuous on compact subsets not imply locally Hölder continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, function-spaces

When Gilbarg and Trudinger introduced the Hölder spaces, they mentioned on page 52 that

> Furthermore note that local Hölder continuity is a stronger property than pointwise Hölder continuity in compact subsets.

without further elaboration.

Can someone kindly explain why?

Comment: For future readers here is [a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT2lY.png) of the page in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easiest to illustrate this for pointwise $\alpha$-Holder functions with $\alpha=1$, i.e., pointwise Lipschitz functions.
Consider
$$f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x^2)$$
for $x$ in  $[-1,1] \setminus\{0\}$, with $f(0)=0$.
The pointwise Lipschitz constant in this case is simply $|f'(x)|$, which is well defined and finite everywhere in $[-1,1]$, but is not bounded in any neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: This is a very helpful counter example.  I think I understand Hölder continuity much better now.  Thank you so much!